# Why Does my loop not work after the third time

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my code, The computer is supposed to guess a number between 1 and 100. The computer's guesses should either decrease or increase by half of the previous guess. The third time through the loop going only higher it breaks, or if I use higher after saying lower it breaks. Both ways, it will stop adding its guesses and divide the previous guess by two, instead of adding the previous guess divided by two to the previous guess. i.e instead of 50 + (50/2) = 75 my code does 50/2 = 25. So where it breaks on higher is at 87, instead of adding half of the previous guess, which would be six, it divides 87 by 2 equaling 43. (I have now edited this question, and the code and everything should work besides where I need help. Thank you)

```
pcguess = 50
useranswer = 50
print("Wanna see a magic trick?")
print("Please think of a random number between 1 and 100.")
print("Now that you have written down your number")
print("I will guess it in ten guesses or less.")
a = print("My first guess is", pcguess)
tries = 0
while tries < 100000:
    newguess = pcguess//2
    b = input("Was that your number?")
    if b == "no":
        tries += 1
        c = input("Is your number higher or lower than my guess?")
        if c == "lower":
            print("Then my next guess is:")
            print(useranswer - newguess )
            useranswer = pcguess - newguess
            pcguess = newguess    
            tries += 1
        elif c == "higher":
            print("Then my next guess is:")
            print(useranswer + newguess)
            useranswer = pcguess + newguess
            pcguess = newguess
            tries += 1
    if b == "yes":
        print("I got it in", tries, "tries!")
        break
```

Comment: Hey @Chrispi. If you found my answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer? It helps people that are having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to narrow down the possible range of numbers based on the user's "higher"/"lower" responses. So you should store the lower and upper bounds as variables, and adjust them as you get responses. Something like this:

```
lower = 0
upper = 100

while lower < upper:
    guess = (lower+upper)//2
    print("My guess is ", guess)
    # Find out if the correct answer is higher or lower than this guess
    if the correct answer is higher:
       lower = guess + 1   # This gives a new lower bound
    if the correct answer is lower:
       upper = guess - 1   # This gives a new upper bound
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would change in your code is your where you increment your `tries` variable. In your current while loop, you are incrementing once every time you execute your while loop and then again after whichever `if` statement gets executed. This means that every iteration, your number of tries goes up by 2 instead of 1. So why don't you just increment `tries` once at the beginning of your loop instead?

Second, the reason your `useranswer` variable doesn't become what you expect is simply because you are updating it wrong. For example

```
        if c == "lower":
        print("Then my next guess is:")
        print(useranswer - newguess )
        useranswer = pcguess - newguess  # WRONG
        pcguess = newguess
```

since you are updating `useranswer`, it should be `useranswer = useranswer + newguess` or more succinctly `useranswer += newguess`

Do this for the other if statement as well (where your guess is higher than what the computer is guessing)

Thirdly. This is more a matter of styling but your `while` loop condition should be more accurate (i.e. since you are telling the user that you will guess their number in 10 tries or less, does your loop condition really need to have `tries < 100000`?